# t as a name of the global variable in R: impossible?

Tags: r, binding, global-variables

I want to use t as a name of the global variable in R but it does not let me.

```
sq1=function() {
  t<<-7
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in sq1() : cannot change value of locked binding for 't'
```

How can I overcome this?

Comment: why do you **need** the variable to be named `t`?

Comment: `t` is reserved because it's a function that transposes a `matrix` or `data.frame`.

Comment: I have an elegant mathematical model where each variable has its name for a reason. I want the code correspond perfectly to the variables of the model

Answer (score 5):

`<<-` has found the `t` in the base package and that is locked but you can still do it by specifying that you want `t` in the Global Environment:

```
f <- function() .GlobalEnv$t <- 7
f()
```

Alternately use: `assign("t", 7, .GlobalEnv)` .

Answer (score 2):

`t` is a function in base R that transposes a matrix.  That is why it has been locked.

I would suggest that you rethink using global variables.  It can create hard to find errors and makes code harder to understand.

Comment: `t` is not locked, you can create an object in the global environment with that name.

Comment: In the OPs context it is locked, but not when `t` is directly set in the global environment.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried re-defining `t` in the global environment first (again, if you **really* need to use that name)?

```
t <- 0
sq1 <- function() {
   t <<- 7
}
```

Note that it's really not a good idea to set globals from within functions. Much better to do something like:

```
sq1 <- function() {
    return(7)
}
t <- sq1()
```

But, it would be better to use another name (even though R will understand when you use it in a function call).

Comment: why is it not a good idea to use globals? I hear this all the time but nobody really explained this w.r.t to R.

Comment: First, we all use globals all the time in R. When you fire up R and start working from the console, you are impacting the current global environment whenever you create new objects (functions or variables). The problem is when you try to manipulate those variables via the `<<-` operator from within other functions. They introduce potentially difficult to trace side effects that might cause serious issues down the road and goes against the principles of modular programming that make R so powerful.

Comment: You also are not guaranteed that `<<-` will set the variable in the global environment.

Comment: @hrbrmstr, I use them to propagate the changes in several data.tables that I am transforming in the script. You suggest using classes for that?

Comment: also, everybody is talking about "potential side effects" but nobody has any evidence

Comment: It's usage-dependent, so it might not be an issue in one script but could be disastrous in another. When you have to spend 3 hrs debugging something caused by mis-using globals, you'll understand.

Comment: Quick quiz:  I set my variable `x` to a value, say `x <- 3`.  Now I run a function that uses global variables, `funWglob(1:10)`.  What is the value of `x`?

Comment: [@Greg Snow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/430909/greg-snow) I wish I cld click the up arrow more than once for that :-)

Comment: @hrbrmstr, I clicked once for you ;) Greg, makes sense, thanks. Is it the only problem?

Answer (score 1):

To add to what @hrbrmstr answered, and show some output.

You could work around this by defining `t` as a variable in the global environment first (not recommended though, since `t` is a base function), and then use `<<-` to redefine it.

It's not a huge deal.  If you think about it, we do it all the time with names like `text <-` and `df <-`.  Those are also functions.  Just be careful, or just choose a new variable if possible.

```
> t <- 5
> t
[1] 5
> sq1=function() {
      t<<-7   }
> sq1()
> t 
[1] 7
```